# Spring 3 MVC redirect: is giving me a 404 when trying to redirect to another controller

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc, view

My view resolver:

```
<bean id="htmlView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerHandler(@Valid RegisterForm registerForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "/account/register";
    }
    return "redirect:/account/profile";
}
```

If there are errors then it returns just fine back to the account registration page. After reading some of the official docs, it appears that redirect will try to resolve the view to the current servlet context. Since "account/profile" resides in another controller, it doesn't seem to know what to do with it. I tried returning a RedirectView without much success either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you redirect you have to add the context name of your application: redirect:/contextname/account/profile Are you sure the url you get is correct?

Comment: What exactly happens? Which URL do you see in the address bar after redirect?

Comment: My application path is "/", so it has no context. The URL is "/account/account/profile.html". If I remove the "/account", then the URL is "/profile.html" If I make it "account/profile", then the URL is "account/profile" without the .html. If I make it "/account/profile.html" then it tries to append the view prefix. There doesn't seem to be any combination that works.

Comment: The fact that you are seeing "/account/account/profile.html" after the redirect is a bit strange. Do you have a "@RequestMapping("account")" annotation on either of your controller class declarations (as opposed to a controller method) by any chance? If you change the other controller to use a different top level directory (e.g. accounts), does it behave the same way? Lastly, try turning on debug level logging for org.springframework, as it will show you which URL paths are getting caught by which controller classes.

Comment: nickdos, thanks for the comment... that was just what I needed. I didn't even think to look at the other controller class request mapping. I just assumed it was the controller doing the redirecting that was incorrect. If you post that in an answer, I will go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you are seeing `/account/account/profile.html` after the redirect is a bit strange. Do you have a `@RequestMapping("account")` annotation on either of your controller class declarations (as opposed to a controller method) by any chance?

If you change the other controller to use a different top level directory (e.g. accounts), does it behave the same way?

Lastly, try turning on debug level logging for org.springframework, as it will show you which URL paths are getting caught by which controller classes.

Comment: Thanks nickdos. For others, please see my comment to the original question for some clarification.